# InvalidSessionIdException and StaleElementReferenceException Errors (Python 3 / Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I think I am in over my head! I am trying to learn python and I started with web scraping and have got to a non-passable point. I am getting InvalidSessionIdException and StaleElementReferenceException errors. I have tried explicit and implicit waits for the Invalid Session Id errors and tried expected conditions for the stale errors. I have tried several different things to no avail. If someone could help me that would be nice and sorry for the code I am only three days into learning python with a little prior experience.

```
'''
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

all_tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AAAU', 'AACG']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for i in range(0, 7661):
    page_num = ('&r=' + str(i * 20 + 1))
    url = 'website' + str(page_num)
    driver.get(url)
    tickers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="screener-content"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody//td[2]/a')))
    company = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="screener-content"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody//td[3]/a')))
    price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="screener-content"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody//td[9]/a')))
    num_of_tickers = len(tickers)
    for i in range(num_of_tickers):
        print(tickers[i].text + " : " + company[i].text + " : " + price[i].text, '', end = '')
        driver.close()

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        for index in all_tickers:
            url = 'website' + index + '/cash-flow?p=' + index
            driver.get(url)
            FCF_TTM = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span')))[0].text
            FCF_2019 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/span')))[0].text
            FCF_2018 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/span')))[0].text
            FCF_2017 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]/span')))[0].text
            FCF_2016 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[6]/span')))[0].text
            print(FCF_TTM,  FCF_2019, FCF_2018, FCF_2017, FCF_2016, '', end = '')
            driver.close()

            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            for index in all_tickers:
                url = 'website' + index + '/key-statistics?p=' + index
                driver.get(url)
                shares_outstanding = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy"]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]')))[0].text
                print(shares_outstanding, '', end = '')
                driver.close()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'website'
driver.get(url)
year_10_bond = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yfin-list"]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]')))[0].text
print(year_10_bond)
driver.close()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementExceptions are thrown because you are storing an element, and then trying to reference it later, but it has changed on the webage. So for example, if you store an element in a variable and then the webpage gets refreshed for some reason, and then you try and reference the variable you stored, it will throw this a stale element exception.

You did not mention where the error is occurring but my guess is it is when you are storing all of the elements in tickers, company, price, and then referencing those elements later when trying to print them in the loop, but they have changed on the webpage.

One way to get around this is to avoid using stored web elements, and call the elements at runtime. So for example

```
num_of_tickers = len(tickers)
for i in range(num_of_tickers):
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span)[{}]").format(i).text)
```

This code will loop through occurrence of the xpath, and since it is doing it at runtime no stale element should be thrown.

Also your xpaths could be more concise, try to use this as a reference https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 0):

The way I wrote the code I thought I was closing and opening the browser for each `for` loop. That is why I did not understand the errors I was getting. However, `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` was outside of the `for` loop. I placed it inside of the for loop and it runs as intended.